# Surface charge of an infinitely long cylinder with uniform polarization

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-fields

I have a polarization in form of;
$$\vec{P}=k\hat{\phi}$$

And I want to find surface surface charges with $\sigma=\vec{P} \cdot \hat{n}$ I found two directions $\hat{r}$ and $\hat{z}$ for two surfaces but both of them are perpendicular to the $\hat{\phi}$ direction.

So can I say that if there is a polarization in $\hat{\phi}$ direction, there are no surface charges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The terminology specifically is *bound* surface charge, but yes. You can say that if your surface is a cylinder and the polarization vector is $\propto \hat{\phi}$.